# Wordpress with Advanced Custom Fields showing post content in Modal

Tags: wordpress, modal-dialog, advanced-custom-fields

I am have a little issue coding a WordPress website with Advance Custom Fields and a modal.

How can I incorporate the modal with the Advanced Custom Fields? Currently the modal just shows a generic name and company.

When I move the modal into the loop it shows the content for every post.

[Pastebin link here](http://pastebin.com/beXRQNKy)

Thanks
Paddy

Comment: That is exactly what you have to do... move the modal into the loop (the acf loop) to show the correct data for each company. If you only want to have one modal on the page showing different data for each company, you'll have to do it with ajax.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alpipego. Could you point me in the direction of some documentation on how I can do it with ajax?

Comment: Are you showing your modal with js/jquery? if yes, could you supply a little code please?

Comment: This is the jQuery I am using to call it in. 
http://pastebin.com/RBKgVwkw

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I have sorted it out by using data attributes.

```
    <div class="content row">
   <ul class="slides">
    <?php query_posts( 'showposts=-1&orderby=asc&category_name=speakers' ); ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php if( have_rows('speakers') ): ?>
                <?php while( have_rows('speakers') ): the_row(); ?>

                    <?php $image = get_sub_field('photo'); ?>
                    <?php $company = get_sub_field('company'); ?>
                    <?php $bio = get_sub_field('bio'); ?>

                    <li class="slide col25 js-open-modal">
                        <a href="#modal1" class="easy-modal-open js-modal-open" data-post-id="<?= get_the_ID(); ?>" data-image-url="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" data-image-alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" data-title="<?php echo the_title(); ?>" data-company="<?php echo $company; ?>" data-bio="This is the bio text">
                        <img class="logo" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />
                        <h4 class="overlay"><?php echo the_title(); ?><br /><?php echo $company; ?></h4></a>
                    </li>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
</div>        


<div class="easy-modal js-modal" id="modal1">
<div class="easy-modal-inner">
    <img class="logo js-logo" src="" alt="" />
    <h4><span class="js-title"></span><span class="js-company"></span></h4>
    <p class="js-bio"></p>
    <button class="easy-modal-close" title="Close">&times;</button>
</div>
</div>
```

// and then using this in my js

```
var modal = $('.js-modal'),
    modalTrigger = $('.js-modal-open');

modalTrigger.on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var t = $(this),
        url = t.data('image-url'),
        alt = t.data('image-alt'),
        title = t.data('title'),
        company = t.data('company'),
        bio = t.data('bio');

updateModal(modal, url, alt, title, company, bio);
// open modal here unless the plugin you are using opens its self?
});

function updateModal(elm, url, alt, title, company, bio) {
elm.find('img').attr('src', url);
elm.find('img').attr('alt', alt);
elm.find('.js-title').text(title);
elm.find('.js-company').text(company);
elm.find('.js-bio').text(bio);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the post id to your link that you are opening the modal with (this will be used to pass the post id to the ajax function):

```
<li class="slide col25">
    <a href="#modal1" class="easy-modal-open" data-post-id="<?= get_the_ID(); ?>">
    //img and h4
    </a>
</li>
```

use `wp_localize_script` to pass the ajaxurl to your jquery:

```
wp_localize_script( 'my_modal', 'my_modal_localize', array(
    ajaxurl => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
) );
```

add a function to query the correct company to your functions.php (something like you have above):

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_custom_function', 'get_company_modal' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_function', 'get_company_modal' );

function get_company_modal() {
    $args = array(
        p => $_POST['post_id'], //this is the post id passed via jquery.post()
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    $result = array();

    if( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();

            // get all your custom fields here and add them to the $result array
            $result[ $custom_field_key ] = $custom_field_value;

        }
    }

    echo json_encode( $result );
    die();
}
```

and then add the call to the `click` event in your jquery using [`.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```
$('.easy-modal-open').click(function(e) {
    var data = {
        action: 'custom_function', //see the add_action part above
        post_id: $(this).data('post-id'), //this is the post id from the a data attribute
    }

    $.post( my_modal_localize.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        var customFields = $.parseJSON(response);

        // add the custom fields to your output via e.g. append()
    }
    // and THEN open the modal 
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target).trigger('openModal');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

maybe you'll need to add a [`$.when().then()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) but that depends on the situation.

So this is only an example and one way of achieving what you want. You will of course edit it to suit your situation.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this. But I am a little unsure where each section goes.
Where does wp_localize_script go and how do I implement my variables? I would be more than happy to pay to get this correct.

Comment: `wp_localize_script()` goes into your functions.php the ajaxurl is then accessible in js through `my_modal_localize.ajaxurl` if you need more help please open a chatroom or find my email address in my profile.